# jQuery loading a url when a thumb loads

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have a mini app that consists of title, thumb, lg_image, url fields. I am loading in these thumbs dynamically by looping over the queryset. Each record has a url in the url field, how would I go about making the lg_image clickable to go to that url field? if it's any help I am using http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/ and basically I need the larger image to navigate to a url provided. I hope this is clear, it was a tad tough to explain. Please advise if not.

Thanks

- JeffC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that plugin uses a custom attribute `longdesc` to make the main image clickable. I don't really like how it's not using a `<a>` tag but if you are trying to make it work for this, give your image tag an attribute of longdesc with a link. Look at the source of the link you provided and also read the comments in the plugin page, people are talking about this very issue.

```
<img src="http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/images/thumbs/t1.jpg" title="A title for 1.jpg" longdesc="http://coffeescripter.com/" alt="This is a nice, and incredibly descriptive, description of the image 1.jpg" class="image0">
```